# Make new volume available on AWS ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

My existing volume ran out of disk space. I followed these instructions to create a new volume based on a snapshot of the old volume:

> Log into the AWS Management Console
>
> Make sure that the Instance that you wish to change is not currently
>   running
>
> Navigate to Elastic Block Store > Volumes
>
> Check the box next to the Volume that needs more space
>
> Click the More… drop down list and select Create Snapshot
>
> Enter a Name and a Description
>
> Navigate to Elastic Block Store> Snapshots
>
> Monitor the progress of the Snapshot for completion
>
> Once complete, navigate back to Elastic Block Store > Volumes
>
> Click Create Volume
>
> Enter the desired size for the new volume
>
> Make sure that you select the same Availability Zone for your instance
>
> Select the Snapshot that you just created
>
> Click Yes, Create
>
> Monitor the progress of the Volume for completion
>
> Once complete, Check the box next to the Volume that is currently
>   connected to the Instance
>
> Make sure that no other Volumes are selected
>
> Click the More… drop down list and select Click the More… drop down
>   list and select Detach Volume
>
> Uncheck the box selected and check the box next to the new Volume
>
> Click the More… drop down list and select Click the More… drop down
>   list and select Attach Volume
>
> Select the Instance that you wish to change
>
> Change the value in Device from xvdf  to /dev/sda1
>
> Click Yes, Attach
>
> Navigate to Instances and start your Instance
>
> Once you are satisfied that the volume works, feel free to delete the
>   Snapshot and old Volume if you like

After following these exact instructions, I log into the ec2 instance and notice the following:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
loop1         7:1    0 93.8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop2         7:2    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
loop3         7:3    0 91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
nvme0n1     259:0    0  100G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

The device `nvme0n1p1` is the one that ran out of disk space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           390M   16M  375M   4% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop1       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop3       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
tmpfs           390M     0  390M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The new volume was created with 100gb of disk space. I think this might be it:

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0  100G  0 disk
```

So my question is how can I make use of this 100G? That was the whole point of creating a new volume..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have skipped the long process to increase the EBS volume size by making use of this feature [Modify EBS Volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/).

---

As you can see, the disk `nvme0n1` has the new size of `100G`, but the root partition is still `8G`. The root partition `nvme0n1p1` has to be extended and its filesystem must be resized.

**1.** Extend the partition

```
growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
```

The `1` represent the partition number, i.e., `nvme0n1p1`.

If `growpart` command does not exist, install it using `apt install cloud-guest-utils`

**2.** Resize the Filesystem

For `xfs`,

```
xfs_growfs -d /
```

In case of `ext` filesystems,

```
resizefs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between nvme0n1 and nvme0n1p1?

Comment: `nvme0n1` is the name of the disk and `nvme0n1p1` is a partition in it. The disk is being split into individual partitions so that each partition can behave as an individual disk and lets the usage of the disk as multiple smaller individual disks rather than one single large disk. You can read more on them [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/partitions.html).

Comment: What if I get error? growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1  ‘/tmp/growpart.23900’: No space left on device

Comment: It needs to write a temporary file during the process, can you free up a few MBs from `/`?

Comment: No, now it won't even let me ssh into it.

Comment: You have to detach the volume, attach (as non root device) it to a different EC2 instance in same availability zone. Login to the instance mount the volume and clean up some files from this volume. Then re-attach to the old instance.

Comment: I was able to get the server back running taking your advice in the comments. I found a very large file and deleted it and then remounted it to the original instance. I will resize the instance to 100gb later. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Please comment here if you come accross any issues proceeding further.